# 'Unable to find a valid app' error building electron app using electron-packager

Tags: electron, electron-packager

When running my application using npm start, everything works fine. However after building my app using electron-packager and open .exe file, it occurs:
'Unable to find a valid app' , complete description is

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLVP0.png)

my packager.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "electron-roll-tool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager ./src/ electron-roll-tool --win --out ../dist --arch=x64 --version=0.0.1 --overwrite --electron-version=1.8.4"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/alex1504/electron-roll-tool",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "electron-packager": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.12.10"
  }
}
```

I change the entry point and my project structure is：

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByesH.png)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `package.json`, the 'build' command is incorrect. Replace `./src/` with `./` and then use `ignore` to exclude files and folders.

Because `electron-packager` needs the `package.json` in the `src` folder to know the main entrance and the dependencies, and also needs the dependencies in `src`